# Remove and uninstall Android NDK

Tags: android-ndk

I tried to uninstall Android NDK since I don't need it any more. The path found in Eclipse seems to be broken. How should I clean up this mess? I tried brew but it said NDK is not installed. (It even told me SDK is not installed! Maybe not installed through brew?) 
I'm using a Mac.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

NDK is just a set of libraries and binary tools.

Normally, you do not need to "uninstall" it.

To "remove" it, you can:

- delete the ndk folder
- remove NDK environnent variable you have set previously

Comment: I used homebrew to install my NDK (which I upgraded via android studio), to remove the homebrew version use `brew list` and then find the package to uninstall and remove it `brew uninstall android-ndk-r10e`.

Answer (score 12):

I am using Android Studio 3.5.3 and could remove or uninstall the obsolete NDK following the procedure listed below:

1. Use Tools->SDK Manager.
2. Go to the "SDK Tools" page in the "Android SDK" menu. REMEMBER to check the checkbox "Show Package Details" at the lower right corner.
3. You'll see all the NDK's you had installed, Un-check the NDK you'd like to uninstall and click "OK" at the bottom right to uninstall the selected NDK

Comment: I think you also need to remove the ndk.dir line from the local.properties file located at the root of your project.